# What is Classification Calibration Theorem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, hinge-loss, surrogate

I have heard from one of my friends

"In binary classification, consider the 0-1 loss (I[y!=f(x)]). Its expectation is the accuracy of the model. Then consider a surrogate risk, like exponential loss or quadratic. CC proves that for some surrogate loss, a sequence of functions that converges to minimal surrogate risk also converges to minimal 0-1 risk. To prove that a surrogate is CC it’s enough that the surrogate is convex, differentiable, and has negative derivative at the origin"

Can I expect a more intuitive and elaborated answer on this? TIA